# How to avoid N+1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I’m building JSON API for a mobile social networking application, users be able to have some posts and other users able to like and comments on those posts.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs :user
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs :user
  belongs :post, counter_cache: true
end

class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :description, :likes_count, :is_liked

  def likes_count
    object.likes.size   # should pull from counter_cache
  end

  # did current_user already like this post
  def is_liked
    object.likes(user_id: scope.id).exists?  # N+1
  end
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.recent
    render json: @posts, each_serializer: PostSerializer
  end
end

# Output of JSON API to mobile client
{
  "id": 1,
  "body": "...",
  "likes_count": 10,
  "is_liked": true
}
```

User logins into mobile clients and make a request to get recent posts when they open the app, but to be able to generate JSON post response with a flag `is_liked`, we need to issue query to hit DB to able to know if the user is already liked the post, so on mobile screen we show that status on each post on screen.

Comment: Did you consider caching the likes in something like Redis?
Another thing you could do is abstract the `liked_by?` into a class method in the `Post` model and then just do the query until you reach the point it doesn't scale and then you can easily insert some caching there using Redis or any other platform

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem here, so let's see if I can help you...

When you add `belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true` in the `Like` model, you must add a column in the `posts` table called `likes_count` type `integer`.

Also, note that counter caches are incremented or decremented when you create or delete a `like`, so if you have some `data` in your `database` it won't work. You have to [reset the counters](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods/reset_counters).

I hope it helps...